# Can't run WoW in virtual machine

Tags: world-of-warcraft, virtualization

When you start World of Warcraft through the VMware Workstation virtual machine, immediately after the introductory video, the game crashes with an error from the screenshot (ERROR #132(0x85100084) Fatal exception). I tried to find solutions both on the official forum of the game and in the VMware tutorials, but everything turned out to be unsuccessful.
What I have tried:

1. Deleted all folders with game settings, cleared game data.
2. Reinstalled the game.
3. Launched the game with the connection disabled (it helped some).
4. Allocated maximum resources to the virtual machine (there were guaranteed enough resources for the stable operation of the game).

What could be the problem if everything is fine when starting the game on the main system? I will be grateful for any help and hints, I will try any methods.

[image]

Comment: Did you do this? https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-FF434E5C-2FEE-48C9-BEAF-943F0536301E.html
btw. I also read stuff like this so I would not recommend to do what you're trying to do: "wouldnt recommend running the game in a vm, there have been multiple cases of people being banned for no particular reason without botting/hacking just for running the game in a virtual machine"

Comment: World of Warcraft requires DX12 there isn’t a virtual machine at this time that supports DX12. What you want isn’t possible

Comment: "with an error from the screenshot" – The text should be posted as actual text. [Rationale here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: WoW is still in active development and still runs on modern operating systems, therefore doesn't need to run in a VM. If you can explain why you're trying to do so, we might help come up with alternative solutions instead.

Comment: "Only evil code would try to access small number memory." - [Mickens, 2013](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/1311_05-08_mickens.pdf) (Capitalization normalized for readability.)